# Remove extra row in printing to file

Tags: r, string

I'm attempting to print to file the output of a `str_split` operation as follows:

```
s <- t(unlist(str_split("foo_bar_0.5", "_"), use.names = FALSE))
write.csv(s, "test.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

With the `row.names = FALSE` argument, I was able to remove the row names. However, this code still writes an extra line with the column names to the file as follows:

```
V1,V2,V3
foo,bar,0.5
```

With the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In write.csv(s, "test.csv", quote = FALSE,  :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
```

I want only the second line. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `write.table` instead of `write.csv` :

```
write.table(s, "test.csv",sep=',', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

write.table has two parameters like sep for putting the delimeter correctly in this case its comma, the other parameter is col.names which is a valid parameter, setting this to False should work for you.

Also as per documentation, if look for ?write.csv, for the ellipsis(...) , it says the following

> ...     arguments to write.table: append, col.names, sep, dec and qmethod
> cannot be altered.

A more detailed explanation is also present in documentation which mentions the warning you are getting:

> write.csv and write.csv2 provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV
> files. They set sep and dec (see below), qmethod = "double", and
> col.names to NA if row.names = TRUE (the default) and to TRUE
> otherwise.
>
> write.csv uses "." for the decimal point and a comma for the
> separator.
>
> write.csv2 uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon for the
> separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in some Western European
> locales.
>
> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to
> ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file.
> Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored,
> with a warning.